# How to access a class member variable in an object (which is also a member of the class)

Tags: c++

Hi I want to accomplish the following. I can create a constructor in the Lower class that takes the object of Upper and in Upper I can pass its own reference to lower but that would create cyclic dependency errors.

Could someone please help me with how to handle this?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Lower {
  public:
    void doSomething() {
      // Do something with the data variable of the Upper class
      cout << data << endl;
    }
    Lower();
};

class Upper {
  public:
    int data;
    Lower lower; // object of Lower class
    Upper() : data(0), lower() {}
};


int main(void) {

  Upper upper();
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can pass its own reference to lower but that would create cyclic dependency errors.

Not if you forward declare `Upper` and move the definition of `doSomething` after the definition of `Upper` like so:

```
#include <iostream>

class Upper; // forward declaration

class Lower {
  public:
    // declaration only, reference to incomplete type is allowed
    void doSomething(Upper &upper); 
};

// Definition of Upper
class Upper { 
  public:
    int data;
    Lower lower; // object of Lower class
    Upper() : data(0), lower() {}
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        this->lower.doSomething(*this);
    }
};

// now the definition, here Upper is a complete type
void Lower::doSomething(Upper &upper) 
{
      // Do something with the data variable of the Upper class
      std::cout << upper.data << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {

  Upper upper;
  
  upper.doSomething(); // prints 0
}
```

Not sure if you wanted to use it like this, but it should demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Which `Upper` instance should `Lower::doSomething` deal with? You can have a `Lower` instance without an `Upper` instance, what then?

If you need access to an `Upper`, you should have a pointer or reference to one.

```
class Upper;

class Lower {
  Upper * upper;
  public:
    void doSomething() {
      std::cout << upper->data << std::endl;
      std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
    Lower(Upper * upper) : upper(upper) {}
};

class Upper {
  public:
    int data;
    Lower lower; // object of Lower class
    Upper() : data(0), lower(this) {}
};
```